# What is the run time complexity of pairwise summation?

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, data-structures, big-o

I read that [numpy uses pairwise summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairwise_summation) as its default algorithm for calculating the sum (as also confirmed by one of the [pull request](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/3685) at numpy github repository)

So for a snippet like the following and in general:

```
data = np.ones((1000,1000))
sum = np.sum(data)

print(sum)
```

What is the run time complexity of pairwise summation? Since it follows a greedy approach similar to `divide and conquer`, it must be on the `log` scale but I am not sure of the exact equation.

Comment: The wikipedia article you linked to says "Pairwise summation is the default summation algorithm in NumPy[4] and the Julia technical-computing language,[5] where in both cases **it was found to have comparable speed to naive summation** (thanks to the use of a large base case)."

Comment: It will still take Ω(n) time to add up `n` arbitrary numbers. Pairwise summation just manages the rounding-error in a predictable fashion. If NumPy's implementation is efficient, the complexity will be Θ(n).

Comment: The only way to get a sublinear complexity is to take advantage of some special property of the data you are summing. (For example, you can add the number 1 to `n` in O(1) time using the formula `sum(1..n) = n(n+1)/2`.)

Comment: Divide-and-conquer itself doesn't provide any kind of speed-up; it's just a way of organizing the subproblems. Quicksort isn't fast because of divide-and-conquer; it's fast because each subarray can be  sorted in-place. Binary search is fast because only *one* of the subproblems is actually tackled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pairwise summation performs exactly the same number of additions as naive summation.

If you're adding up floating point numbers, though, then a naive summation ends up adding small numbers to big numbers near the end.  This causes numbers near the end to suffer larger rounding errors.

For this reason, pairwise summation would be preferred.